# Do we include a composite key of a week entity (partial key + foreign key from owner entity) as a foreign key or just the partial key?

Tags: database, erd, rdbms

In the conversion of an Entity Relationship Model to a Relational Data Model:

**When mapping a 1:N Binary Relationship, should we include (as a foreign key) *the composite key* (partial key + foreign key from the owner entity) of the entity on the 1 side of the relationship to the relation corresponding to the entity type on the N side of the relationship, *or just the partial key***?

**Background:-**

While transforming an Entity-Relationship Model into a Relational Data Model, the following steps are followed:

1. Map regular entity types into relations, including their single valued attributes.
2. Map week entity types into relations. Include in the relation the Primary Key attribute of its Identifying (i.e. Owner) Entity Type as  a Foreign Key. The key of this relation is a combination of its Partial Key and the Foreign Key from its Identifying Entity Type.
3. Map Binary 1:1 Relationship Types by including the Primary Key of one entity type (which is not showing a Total Participation, if only one of the two participating entity types is showing a total participation in the relationship) as a Foreign Key in the relation corresponding to the other entity type (the one showing the total participation in the relationship.
4. Map Binary 1:N Relationship Types by including the Primary Key of the participating entity type towards to 1 side, as a Foreign Key in the relation corresponding to the entity type towards to N side of the relationship.
5. Map the Binary Relationship M:N by making a new relation for the Relationship Type and making its Composite Key by including Primary Keys of both the participating entity types as Foreign Keys.
6. Make a new relation for each multivalued attribute and make its Key by including Primary Key from its entity type as a Foreign Key.

Reference: [ERM to RDM](https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs338/slides/13%20ER%20to%20Rel.pdf)

**Question explained:-**

1. My first question is from step 3.

If, in step 2, a week entity type's patial key had been combined with a foreign key from its owner relationship to form a composite key in the corresponding relation for the week entity type,

and the same week entity type is showing a total participation in a `1:1 binary relationship`,

and then in step 3, when we are required to add a foreign key from the (although owner) entity type which is not the one showing the `total participation` to the relation corresponding to the (although week) entity type which is showing total participation, ***BUT we have already done that in the previous step as a requirement of that step*, what will we do? Nothing, just move on?**

1. My next question is from step 4, if the entity type towards the 1 side of the relationship is actually a week entity, and thus its primary key is (now, after following the previous step 2) a combination of its own partial key and the foreign key from its identifying relationship, **shall we add this composite key as a foreign key in the entity type towards the N side of the relationship, or just its partial key?**

Answer (score 0):

this rule is only for binary relationships that have strong entities on both side i.e. both of the entities have primary key.
if their is weak entity then it will defenitly be on many (N) side of this relationship in that case we again follow the same rule but the primary key of the relation you built w. r. t. weak enity will be combination of partial key (if any) and primary key of owner (strong) entity.